# What's the deal with the new rarity level in the Captain Scarlett DLC?

Tags: borderlands-2

I heard Captain Scarlett and Her Pirate's Booty has a new rarity level; something pinkish? How will I recognize the new guns, and how do I find them?

Answer (score 4):

It's called Seraph weapons

[image]

and will be acquired by trading the new currency "Seraph" to a vendor in Oasis after doing Hyperius The Invincible and Master Gee The Invincible quests.

[Source](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Seraph)

Comment: Gotta love the reference to Office Space. I absolutely loved that movie.