# Are there Rare Drops in Captain Scarlett?

Tags: borderlands-2

After completing the DLC I've become aware that the [new rarity level items](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89214/whats-the-deal-with-the-new-rarity-level-in-the-captain-scarlett-dlc) can only be *purchased* (with a special currency). I didn't notice any oranges (period) while playing, particularly new oranges, though I noticed a few unique (probably common) drops from bosses.

Are there any rare (legendary/orange) drops in the Captain Scarlett DLC or are Seraph weapons and the new blue Uniques the only new equipment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no new legendary items unique to the DLC, only some blue and purple rarity items.
And regarding the Seraph crystals, they no longer drop on normal/TVHM, only on UVHM.

Both raid bosses hyperius and master gee have chance to drop variety of legendaries from the main campaign and some seraph items.

Generally the Sandhawk and Rapier are the only worthwhile items on the DLC and they are both easily obtainable by just playing through the dlc.
Leviathan's lair has a pretty good chance to drop great relics and mods.

Answer (score 0):

What i can tell for sure about the Captain Scarlett DLC loot is the following:

Quests rewards: 
SMG which shoots bullets in a flying bird pattern
Sniper rifle from which bullets explode into shock bombs upon impact

I found a legendary nade mod "Rolling Thunder" in one the chests.

You can read more info about the loot table in this post [B2 Pirate DLC Treasures](http://www.kotaku.com.au/2012/10/one-easy-tip-for-finding-buried-treasure-in-borderlands-2s-new-pirate-dlc/)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: [Rolling thunder](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Rolling_Thunder) is actually from the main game (of course main game items show up in the DLC too)

Answer (score 0):

Did not notice any oranges, though they can theoretically drop from anyone.

Comment: Have to correct myself: Just found an orange one during the second take at the Leviathan.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of new loot in this DLC. There are new unique items, the seraph (pink) items, a lot of white, green, blue, and purple items, and new e-tech items. There are no new orange items that I've seen. However, the raid bosses do drop some of the old orange weapons. The armory at the end of the game also has a pretty high drop rate for orange items.